# google charts addcolumn not working

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

see code below, i was using inline table and converted to add column and add rows so i could specify the column type - this code will not display any error or render chart...what's wrong - thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", '1.1', {packages:['corechart', 'annotationchart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'TimeStamp');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Temp(F)');
    data.addColumn('number', 'pH');
    data.addRows([ 
        [new Date(2014,02,04,15,15,14), 58.75, 7.97],
        [new Date(2014,02,04,15,15,19), 58.78, 7.93],
        [new Date(2014,02,04,15,23,08), 58.69, 7.94],
        [new Date(2014,02,04,20,49,46), 58.10, 7.94],
        [new Date(2014,02,04,21,14,15), 57.99, 7.92],
        [new Date(2014,02,04,21,15,05), 57.99, 7.92]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Temperature compensated pH',
        curveType: "function",
        hAxis: {format: 'e hh:mm:ss a'},     
        vAxes: {0: {logScale: false, minValue: 40}, 1: {logScale: false}},
        series: {0: {targetAxisIndex: 0}, 1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>pH Logger</h1>
<hr>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `new` keyword before the `google.visualization.DataTable()` constructor call:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```